# Jenkins interpretation of multiple object declarations on one line

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This isn't a question, but rather a cautionary tale:
I tried to save some space and declared my variables in Jenkins Declarative pipeline like so:

```
int a, b, c
```

Then, I initialized them as:

```
a = b = c = 0
```

In my code, I use these integers as counters in a for-loop. My script kept failing over and over, some of the exceptions thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method next() on null object
```

and I knew for sure that my list is valid since it was hard-coded.
So, I started wondering what's going on with these counters and when I called getClass() on them, Jenkins happily told me that they weren't integers, but rather

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

After changing code to

```
int a = 0
int b = 0
int c = 0
```

everything worked like a charm.
Just wanted to share this. Maybe it'll help someone to save some frustration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jenkins pipelines execute Groovy code in the continuation-passing style using [groovy-cps](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps) interpreter. This is not vanilla Groovy you can execute directly in the IDE or in Groovy Shell.

Groovy CPS transforms your code to support the continuation-passing style and the correct Groovy expression like:

```
a = b = c = 0
```

gets transformed to something that looks more like:

```
eval(
  var("a"), 
  assign(
    eval(
      var("b"), 
      assign(
        eval(
          var("c"), 
          assign(0)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The problem with this expression in the CPS interpreter is that the assignment does not return any value, and thus the `null` value gets assigned to the variable `b`, and the same thing happens to the variable `a`.

If you want to dig deeper in the CPS invocations block, you can clone groovy-cps project and write a simple test case in the `com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformerTest` class.

```groovy
@Test
void testMultiVariablesInlineCPS() {
    def cps = parseCps('''
int a, b, c
a = b = c = 0
''')
    println cps
}
```

Then you can put a breakpoint at the `println cps` and run the debugger. When you open the inspection window, you will see the picture similar to this one:

[image]

As a side note, keep in mind that the Groovy compiler also transforms your single line assignments when compiled the code to the bytecode. If you compile a simple Groovy script like:

```groovy
int a, b, c
a = b = c = 0

println "$a $b $c"
```

and then you open its class file in the IDE to decompile the bytecode to the Java equivalent, you will see something like this:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class test extends Script {
    public test() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    }

    public test(Binding context) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        var1[0].call(InvokerHelper.class, test.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        byte var5 = 0;
        return var1[1].callCurrent(this, new GStringImpl(new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(var5), Integer.valueOf(var5), Integer.valueOf(var5)}, new String[]{"", " ", " ", ""}));
    }
}
```